# Записать переменную в кэш

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="number>100</div>
```

При клике на цифру, она увеличивется на 1(это функционал уже есть написан). При перезагрузке страницы, нужно сохранить значение, тоесть 101.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache а тут вам ничего не помогло?

Comment: Можно использовать localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, к сожалению, localStorage не поддерживается на этом сайте.

Код можно запустить [тут](https://jsbin.com/dizotojape/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div')
let number = +localStorage.getItem('number')
setNumber()

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(i => {
  i.onclick = () => {
    const operator = i.textContent
    const res = number + +`${operator}1`

    //localStorage.setItem('number', res)
    localStorage.setItem('number', res)
    setNumber()
  }
})

function setNumber () {
  number = el.textContent = +localStorage.getItem('number')
}
```

```html
<div class="number">123</div>
<button>+</button>
<button>-</button>
```